# How to solve error "PostgreSQL: 40001: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery" when loading a PostgreSQL table into powerBI

Tags: postgresql, powerbi

A few things to add to the question above. The database in question we're trying pull from is created specifically for this. There is one user only and there is no replication activated, so as far as I understand nothing should be interrupting the processes on the side of the DB. Are there some kind of limitations in the amount of data that could trigger this? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I do not get this kind of error when I run queries directly on the DB, I only get it when loading tables from this DB into powerBI.

To note, I have checked the various other topics on this and they don't seem to provide answers to this.

Comment: This error should only be thrown on a replica.  I don't see how it could be thrown in any other situation.  It is possible for 40001 to be thrown in other situations, but not with that wording.

Comment: there may be some hints in the server logs